# List variable is not getting exposed from WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am writing a WCF Service which exposed the parameter Pin, gender and addresses. I am consuming the service using WCF Client. In the Client I can see only the simple parameters Pin and gender. I could not see the `List<PatronAddress>`. I have added `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` for the patron address class. Can some one let me know how to expose the List from WCF? Thanks.

Code is below.

```
[DataContract]
public class EnrollPatronInformation
{       
    [DataMember]
    public string Pin { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public enums.eGenderType Gender { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<PatronAddress> Address { get; set; }        
}

[DataContract]
public class PatronAddress
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ContactType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Line1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Line2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Postal { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured your service to accept Generic Lists?

Comment: Show us your client code

Comment: I have not written any code. I am just consuming the service through WCF Client Tool provided by Microsoft .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is output field use Array for it.
You don't need to provide a List to a client.
For Arrays it usually works